# Is there any tool that can help me know the DAU (Daily Active Users) and MAU (monthly active users) of my flutter/Dart Application?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have a mobile application that is currently in development mode. i want to track my MAU, DAU and the user retention rate of my application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could track this using the Firebase platform.
I would suggest using Firebase analytics for retrieving this type of data.

You can find it here at: https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics

Comment: You should ask users for consent though, either out of politeness, or legal requirements (e.g. EU privacy laws). You should also offer an easy opt-out, even later while using the app.